# Prove : $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2\ge a(b+c+d+e)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, summation

Prove that by Cauchy inequality : $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2\ge a(b+c+d+e).$$
$a,b,c,d,e$ - different and positive numbers .

Comment: This is the second question you ask today and this one has the same problem the other had. When you ask a question you need to include context and the work you've done to try to solve it (or at least some ideas). Questions like “this is my problem, fix it” usualy go unanswered or are closed.

Comment: Yeah, this question does not meet the MSE Guidelines. -1 and Vote-To-Close

Comment: Maybe you can try the simpler inequality 2 or 3 variables.

Comment: put everything on the left hand side, it is a quadratic form, the Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite, and the $\pm$ signs of the variables do not matter. We do get equality for $(a,b,c,d,e) = (2,1,1,1,1)$  or any multiple of that. Most likely that was what they had in mind when demanding distinct variable values, as then equality is no longer possible and the inequality is strict.

Answer (score 0):

**First let's show:** $\frac{ab+ac-b^{2}-c^{2}}{a^{2}}-\frac{1}{2}\leq0$:
$\iff ab+ac-b^{2}-c^{2}-\frac{a^{2}}{2}\leq0$
Which as a frown parabola of the variable $a$ achieves maximum at $a=b+c$.
the maximum is $-b^{2}+bx-c^{2}+cx-\frac{x^{2}}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}(b-c)^{2}<0$ as we wanted.

---

**Now let's show that:** $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}+e^{2}-a\cdot(b+c+d+e+fa)\geq0$
where $f=\frac{ab+ac-b^{2}-c^{2}}{a^{2}}-\frac{1}{2}$.

---

**It simplifies to:**
$d^{2}+e^{2}-ad-ae-fa^{2}\geq ab+ac-(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2})$
$(d-\frac{a}{2})^{2}+(e-\frac{a}{2})^{2}-\frac{a^{2}}{2}-fa^{2}\geq ab+ac-(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2})$
$(x-\frac{a}{2})^{2}+(y-\frac{a}{2})^{2}\geq0$
which is true. Q.E.D

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

Use Cauchy Schwartz to show
$$b + c + d + e \leq 2\sqrt{b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2}$$
Then use any method you prefer to show
$$2a \sqrt{b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2} \leq a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2$$